# How to check if a number is within the range of the same number including float type

Tags: php

How to check if number is within the range of 36 for example

the range is 36 , how to check if number is either 36.1,36.2,.....36.9 in PHP ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [floor](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.floor.php). It will round down to the next lowest integer. Example:

```
$number = '36.3';
if (floor($number) == 36)
{
    echo 'Thirty-six';
}
```